# command in perl script not working

Tags: perl

When I place this command in a perl script, it won't work:

```
`chkconfig --level 3 nslcd on`;
```

But if I execute it on a linux command shell, it works.

```
[root@barf Scripts]# chkconfig --level 3 nslcd on
```

I'm curious on why it does't work in a perl script.

TIA

Comment: Doesn't work is a strong statement. Does it sit on the couch all day? Does it want more money? Is it on Serverfault all the time? Please be specific!

Comment: "Doesn't work" means the service did not start after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Does using

```
print `chkconfig --level 3 nslcd on`;
```

instead "fix" it?
If yes, the answer is found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec

*Backticks in Perl execute with a system() call, and their return value will be the STDOUT of the called command.*

Comment: It didn't work (print `chkconfig --level 3 nslcd on`;) Maybe because a.pl calls b.pl which has the chkconfig --level 3 nslcd on in it?

Comment: After your clarification on the question: Do you run the perl script with root permissions as well?

Comment: Yes, I do run the perl script with root permissions.